# folder size mismatch when cloning a git repo

Tags: linux, git

I created very large git repository. Following are the commands I used (creating repo, checking folder size & sharing over network),

```
>git init
>git add .
>git commit -m "Initial commit"
>du -sh .
11G   .
>git daemon --export-all --base-path=$(pwd)
```

On another system (same LAN network), I cloned this repository. But checking the folder size,

```
REMOTE>git clone git://192.168.1.19/ myandroid
REMOTE>cd myandroid
REMOTE>du -sh .
8.9G   .
REMOTE>
```

We can see that it isn't the same. :( Does anyone know why? The way I understand git (consider that cloning means to download the entire repository), shouldn't the folder sizes be the same?

NOTE: There are no ".gitignore" files anywhere. I ran,

```
>find . -name ".gitignore" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

To double-check before making the repo.

EDIT: Both systems are running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit. One is an i3-based laptop and the remote is a Core 2 desktop.

Answer (score 2):

your object files have been repacked, read: http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-4.html

Comment: I think it's helpful to explain that on the original repository, the files are "loose", while the repacked versions are compressed and deltafied.